# mustache js fail to load view as an array from json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mustache

I am trying to load my data from my JSON file but apparently only the first attribute was loaded. I created an array by using jQuery push method to extract the data from my JSON file. When I see the array output from console.log, it looks fine. 
[image: only the first attribute was loaded]
I don't get what went wrong

my html

```
 <h2>My message list </h2>
{{#msg}}
<img src= {{icon}} >
{{subject}}             
{{detail}}
{{date}}
{{/msg}}
```

my Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadUser1(){
    var template = $('#template').html();
    Mustache.parse(template);   // optional, speeds up future uses
        $.getJSON( "messages.json", function( data ) {
             console.log('loaded');
             var messageslist = []; // create array here
             $.each(data.messages, function (index, message) {
             messageslist.push("{icon:'"+message.icon+"',subject:'"+message.subject+",detail:'"+message.detail+"',date:'"+message.date+"'}"); //push values here            
            });
             console.log(messageslist);//see output
             var rendered = Mustache.render(template,{"msg":messageslist});
             $('#target').html(rendered);
        });
    }
    </script>
```

The array shows in the console: (I have repetitive dummy data in json)

```
Array [ "{icon:'images/alert_bad.png',subject:'Supply Chain - Past Due,detail:'Gerry Harrison',date:'01/16/2015'}", "{icon:'images/alert_bad.png',subject:'Supply Chain - Past Due,detail:'Gerry Harrison',date:'01/16/2015'}", "{icon:'images/alert_bad.png',subject:'Supply Chain - Past Due,detail:'Gerry Harrison',date:'01/16/2015'}" ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating object as JSON string instead of javascript object, try this:

```
var rendered = Mustache.render(template,{"msg": data.messages});
```

the data.messages is already correct not need to push to another array.